# use user defined number to create countdown timer

Tags: android, android-edittext, countdowntimer

We are using 2 edittext, one to enter hours and one to enter Minutes.

---

```
int CountM; 
int CountT;

@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Mylabel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Hours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Timer);
    Minuttes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Minutter);


void StartTimer()
{
    int TotalT = ((CountT*60*60)+(CountM*60)*1000);

    mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerTextView);
    CountDownTimer aCounter = new CountDownTimer(TotalT, 1000)
    {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
         {
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }
         public void onFinish() 
         {
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + CountM + CountT);
         }
    };
     aCounter.start();
}
```

As you can see we need to collect data from our `Edittext` from `Hours into CountT` and `Minutes into CountM` and spit those results out, get it down to seconds so we can set it to do a task 5 hours later. 
We have tried with strings and converting them into Ints.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the issue? What doesn't work?

Comment: might be stupid, but did you try to call StartTimer() function? And yes, one more time, what is the issue? What do you get and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Button` in your layout, on clicking which, you need to start the timer, the code for the same would be:

```
Button startBtn;
@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Mylabel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Hours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Timer);
    Minuttes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Minutter);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             try{
                 String hourStr = Hours.getText().toString();
                 CountT = Integer.parseInt(hourStr);
                 String minuteStr = Minuttes.getText().toString();
                 CountM = Integer.parseInt(minuteStr);
                 StartTimer();
             }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
    });
}
```

A suggestion: While you are still learning, it would be a good idea to understand and follow the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: We can now preorder our coffee 8hours ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing:

((CountT*60*60)+(CountM*60)*1000); // expand it a bit:

( (CountT*60*60) + (CountM*60)*1000 ); // hours/CountT not multiplied by 1000

If there is any doubt whatsoever about operator precedence, use extra brackets.
If there is no doubt whatsoever about operator precedence, use extra brackets.

Debugging 101 tip #34 - break up complex expressions into simpler ones that load separate local vars so that the exact sequence of operations can easily be seen in the debugger.  If you had written:

```
int minsTicks=CountM*60*1000;
int hoursTicks=CountT*60*60;
int totalTicks=hoursTicks+minsTicks;
```

you would have seen straightaway the problem, in fact, you would probably not have made it in the first place!

Comment: Will remember to keep it simpel next time, for easier debugging.
The problem is solved by Rajesh, currently below your answer. 
We had just missed information on to correctly convert it into a int.